# letter count in a sentence using Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Suppose I have a string `"I am a good boy"`. I want the total count of each letter present in the string. Letters are case sensitive. i.e., `D` and `d` need to be considered as two different characters.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's expected you show code you've written to try to solve the problem. This question is asked often here so some searching should have turned up many examples of how to accomplish it.

Comment: This sure looks like homework to me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
"I am a good boy".scan(/\w/).inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, c| h[c] += 1; h}
# => {"I"=>1, "a"=>2, "m"=>1, "g"=>1, "o"=>3, "d"=>1, "b"=>1, "y"=>1}
```

Comment: @sawa No need your one,as ponited gem internally doing this. You might copy that code as an answer.I will go with the `gem`.@Logan already linked that code.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan No I will not. I already have mine. There is no need to.

Comment: Who is down voting this?  This answer takes advantage of a reduce statement and is much more efficient.

Comment: @RubyLovely google for `inject(Hash.new(0))`; it's just the way everybody counts frequencies.

Comment: @steenslag in what way you think my one will not work? while i was counting and updating the `key` value, the reduce is doing a new object creation for each `1` increment `h[c] += 1`.

Comment: @RubyLovely Your code does work, but not very efficient. On the first appearance of the letter 'o' it scans the whole string, counts all o's, and stores the result (3) in the hash. On the second 'o' it does the same thing, etc.

Comment: @steenslag yes, it is a search,not the new object creation. **notice** carefully. It just performed its searching and updating. Not object creation and updation.

Comment: @RubyLovely: If you're going to start arguing about performance and efficiency then you should back it up with benchmark results, otherwise it is just hand waving.

Answer (score 15):

```
a = "I am a good boy"

a.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }
```

Comment: @muistooshort, because `a.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }` not removing `white spaces` I think.

Comment: "because a.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] } not removing white spaces I think." What?! That has nothing to do with spaces. `chars` is an iterator over the individual characters in a string. `group_by(&:chr)` groups by the character and returns a hash where each character key has a value of an array of the same character occurrences. `map` converts each hash to the character and the size of the array. `to_a` isn't necessary, but was probably habit. `sort` is a convenience.

Comment: @theTinMan did you run this code `a.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }`? Try it first.

Comment: @RubyLovely: I'd recommend that you try it yourself and look carefully at the results with and without the `.to_a.sort`. I'd also recommend that you put down the shovel before you dig yourself into a hole that you can't get out of.

Comment: @muistooshort to whome you chanllenged - **look the output** `[["I", 1], [" ", 4], ["a", 2], ["m", 1], ["g", 1], ["o", 3], ["d", 1], ["b", 1], ["y", 1]]` with the code `a.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }`. This output is not expected as per the `OP`.

Comment: @RubyLovely: And you get the same results (in a different order) from `a.chars.to_a.sort.group_by...`. Please step away from the computer and go do something else for awhile, you're embarrassing yourself with all this unprofessional behavior.

Comment: @muistooshort you look here `[" ", 4]`, this was not expeted.

Comment: @RubyLovely: Which has nothing whatsoever to do with the difference between `a.chars.to_a.sort.group_by...` and `a.chars.group_by...`, that's what Tin Man was trying to tell you before you flipped out and tried to change the subject. I think all that digging is making you tired.

Answer (score 8):

This is not meant to be an answer, just an addition to the existing answers.

Because performance was discussed, here is some data.

```
require 'benchmark'

s0 = "I am a good boy"
s = s0 * 1
N = 10000

Benchmark.bm(20) do | x |
  x.report('sawa') do
    N.times { s.scan(/\w/).inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, c| h[c] += 1; h} }
  end

  x.report('digitalross') do 
    N.times { s.chars.to_a.sort.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] } }
  end

  x.report("digitalross'") do 
    N.times { s.chars.group_by(&:chr).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] } }
  end

  x.report('rubylovely') do
    N.times { s.gsub(/\s/,'').chars.with_object({}) {|c,ob| ob[c] = s.count(c)} }
  end
end
```

gives (`ruby 1.9.3p392` on my machine)

```
                           user     system      total        real
sawa                   0.600000   0.000000   0.600000 (  0.601734)
digitalross            0.790000   0.000000   0.790000 (  0.806674)
digitalross'           0.640000   0.010000   0.650000 (  0.651802)
rubylovely             0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.572501)
```

With `s = s0 * 1000` and `N = 10` I get

```
                           user     system      total        real
sawa                   0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.340617)
digitalross            0.380000   0.000000   0.380000 (  0.411393)
digitalross'           0.230000   0.010000   0.240000 (  0.243389)
rubylovely             6.530000   0.000000   6.530000 (  6.603198)
```

So for very short strings, the multiple counting of RubyLovely's solution does not hurt. In reality, it certainly does.

Comment: BTW, I have deleted my answer. But thanks for showing the `Benchmark` report.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use:

```
str = "I am a good boy"
str.scan(/[[:alpha:]]/i).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "I" => 1,
    "a" => 2,
    "m" => 1,
    "g" => 1,
    "o" => 3,
    "d" => 1,
    "b" => 1,
    "y" => 1
}
```

I prefer using `scan` because the regex it uses immediately determines which characters are allowed to be counted. If the input string contained "I am a good boy." some of the other solutions would fail because they are too specific to the input string and would require tweaking each time an unexpected character was encountered. We know that inputs are rarely that sterile and in the real-world this sort of code would be used for general sentences. Ignoring unwanted characters up front is important.

---

```
'Français'.scan(/[[:alpha:]]/i).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "F" => 1,
    "r" => 1,
    "a" => 2,
    "n" => 1,
    "ç" => 1,
    "i" => 1,
    "s" => 1
}
```

Comment: you perfomed a single search, where as I did for all charters except the count of `white spaces`. But take a count how many times you created a new object? Which I didn't. Here is my code goes to efficient list.

Comment: How many times did I create a new object? Explain this in detail so we can all benefit from your knowledge of how it is a bad algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with spelling out a piece of code, so it's easy for any Ruby programmer, including a newbie, to understand it. And, I want to make one pass over that string.

So, I like this:

```
s = "I am a good boy"

def count_word_characters(s)
    h = Hash.new(0)
    s.each_char do |char| 
        next unless char =~/\w/
        h[char] += 1
    end
    h
end
```

because:

- it's easy to see how the hash h is created, filled, and output
- hash h is filled in one pass over the input string
- it's clear we're skipping over non-word characters